# Sort columns of dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a df in R which is made up of a series of column named like this

```
Jan-2018 | Jan-2019 | Feb-2018 | Feb-2019 | Delta Jan 2018 | Delta Feb 2019
```

I should sort the column order in order to have

```
Jan-2018 | Jan-2019 | Delta Jan | Feb-2018 | Feb-2019 | Delta Feb
```

How achieve that in a smart way, knowing that this dataframe is a report which is generated at the beginning of the month, so every month we will have 3 more column i.e current month, same month of 2018 and delta between them.

Thanks

Comment: `df[,sort(colnames(fd))]`?

Comment: Where did `2018` and `2019` from deltas go?

Answer (score 1):

If the order of columns are always sorted by years here is one way.

```
x <- c("Jan-2018", "Jan-2019", "Feb-2018", "Feb-2019", 
       "Delta Jan 2019", "Delta Feb 2019")

x[order(match(sub(paste0(".*(", paste0(month.abb, collapse = "|"), 
                  ").*"), "\\1", x), month.abb))]

#[1] "Jan-2018"  "Jan-2019"  "Delta Jan 2019" "Feb-2018" "Feb-2019" "Delta Feb 2019"
```

Replace `x` by `colnames(df)` and subset the columns from dataframe to get it in required order.

We dynamically create the regex to extract month from the names

```
paste0(".*(", paste0(month.abb, collapse = "|"), ").*")
#[1] ".*(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec).*"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is super hacky but should work:

```
df <- structure(list(`Jan-2018` = 1, `Jan-2019` = 2, `Feb-2018` = 2, 
    `Feb-2019` = 3, `Delta Jan` = 1, `Delta Feb` = 1), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  gather() %>%
  mutate(KPI = case_when(grepl("-[0-9]{4}$",key)~substr(key,5,8), TRUE ~ "Delta"), Month = factor(gsub("Delta |-[0-9]{4}$","",key), levels = c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"))) %>%
  arrange(Month,KPI) %>%
  select(-KPI,-Month) %>%
  mutate(key = factor(key, levels = as.vector(key))) %>%
  spread(key,value)
```

The magic here works in gathering the columns to a variable, saving the right order as the factor levels and then spreading on that sorted factor. The month factor levels need to be hard coded in but they should not change anyway, the rest is automatic.